# Arrow from inset plot to main plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw an arrow from an inset plot to the main plot.  The problem is that the coordinate positions are different in these two plots.  What I want is this:
[image]

What I am getting is ithis:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
  height=3in,
  width=\textwidth,
  %name=mainplot,
  separate axis lines,
  every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  inner xsep=1pt,
  inner ysep=1pt,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=1,
  xtick={  0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8,   1},
  xlabel={\scriptsize Test},
  xmajorgrids,
  ylabel style={yshift=0.4cm}, %shifting the y line text
  every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=603,
  ytick={  0, 200, 400, 600},
  ymajorgrids,
  axis background/.style={fill=white}
  ]
  \addplot [color=blue,solid,line width=0.5pt]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  0     268\\
  0.3   546\\
  0.6   129\\
  0.9   43\\
  1      0\\
  };
  %\coordinate (insetPosition) at (rel axis cs:0.53,0.63);
  \coordinate (insetPosition) at (axis cs:0.65,300);
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[%
  width=1.5in,
  height=1in,
  at={(insetPosition)},
  scale only axis,
  separate axis lines,
  every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  every y label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  inner xsep=1pt,
  inner ysep=1pt,
  xlabel near ticks,
  ylabel near ticks,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10,
  xtick={1,  4,  7, 10},
  xmajorgrids,
  every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=20,
  ytick={ 0, 10, 20},
  ymajorgrids,
  axis background/.style={fill=white}
  ]
  \addplot [color=black,solid,line width=0.5pt]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  1 20\\
  10 0\\
  };
  \node[anchor=west] (pairs_s) at (rel axis cs:0.7,0.8) {\tiny Pairs};
  \node (pairs_d) at (rel axis cs:0.9,0.1) {};
  \draw[->,>=stealth](pairs_s) -- (pairs_d);
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%

  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mybe this will help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173605/draw-a-line-between-data-points-in-two-different-pgfplots-subfigures

Comment: Yes, that's a helpful and related links.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the coordinates in the local coordinate system and draw the arrow in the surrounding tikzpicture.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
...
\coordinate (arrowFrom) at (axis cs:....);
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
...
\coordinate (arrowTo) at (axis cs:....);
\end{axis}
\draw[->] (arrowFrom) -- (arrowTo);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
  height=3in,
  width=\textwidth,
  %name=mainplot,
  separate axis lines,
  every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  inner xsep=1pt,
  inner ysep=1pt,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=1,
  xtick={  0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8,   1},
  xlabel={\scriptsize Test},
  xmajorgrids,
  ylabel style={yshift=0.4cm}, %shifting the y line text
  every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=603,
  ytick={  0, 200, 400, 600},
  ymajorgrids,
  axis background/.style={fill=white}
  ]
  \addplot [color=blue,solid,line width=0.5pt]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  0     268\\
  0.3   546\\
  0.6   129\\
  0.9   43\\
  1      0\\
  };
  \coordinate (insetPosition) at (axis cs:0.65,300);
  \coordinate (arrowTo) at (axis cs:0.7,120);
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[%
  width=1.5in,
  height=1in,
  at={(insetPosition)},
  scale only axis,
  separate axis lines,
  every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  every y label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  inner xsep=1pt,
  inner ysep=1pt,
  xlabel near ticks,
  ylabel near ticks,
  xmin=1,
  xmax=10,
  xtick={1,  4,  7, 10},
  xmajorgrids,
  every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=20,
  ytick={ 0, 10, 20},
  ymajorgrids,
  axis background/.style={fill=white}
  ]
  \addplot [color=black,solid,line width=0.5pt]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
  1 20\\
  10 0\\
  };
  \coordinate (arrowFrom) at (axis cs:8,15);
  \end{axis}
  \draw[-stealth,red](arrowFrom) node[above]{\tiny Pairs} -- (arrowTo);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Move the `pairs_d` `node` definition from the second to the first `axis` environment; (as @gernot suggested, change `\node (name) at (where) {};` to `\coordinate (name) at (where);` to have a cleaner source.)
- add the option `remember picture` to the `tikzpicture` environment;
- add one more `tikzpicture` environment with options `remember picture, overlay` in which you `draw` the line from one point to the other.

I was already writing this answer when @gernot posted his one, which - to be honest - is much cleaner than mine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and to @gernot for the making changes to the code to produce what I want.